# CSS multi-column layout prevent moving columns when height changed

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

Trying to figure how to prevent columns from moving when we have changed height of column. 
Look JSFiddle, try to click links in 3 column to see: https://jsfiddle.net/g305643f/1/

If you want to offer a solution with non multi columns - this task of building columns can be realized using other methods under the following condition:

On desktop we need this:

```
1 3 5
2 4
```

On tablet:

```
1 4
2 5
3
```

Didn't find solution with flex/float/inline-blocks so made it with multi-columns and now find this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function(e){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.sections {
  -webkit-column-gap:41px;
  -moz-column-gap:41px;
  column-gap:41px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
.section {
  -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-before: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.open {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sections">
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x310" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    
    <a href="#" class="open">Open & raise height</a>
    <div class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x320" />
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x330" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x340" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
  <a href="#" class="open">Open & raise height</a>
    <div class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x320" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="open">Open & raise height</a>
    <div class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x320" />
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any fiddle code should be included in your post.

Comment: Added snippet, look

Comment: Are column going to change once page is loaded or is it just that number of items is unknown before loaded ? Would grid CSS do or does it need to behave like masonry js-script?

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries will nice to use in this scenario to define different style rules for different media types/devices,

In your example, you can write if device is mobile use 1 column, if device is tablet use 2 column and if device is desktop use 3 column, [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/getting-started-with-css-media-queries) is great blog from Dan Wahlin on Media Query

Something like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function(e){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
 /*Phone*/
@media only screen and (max-width:320px)
{
  .sections {
 
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
}
  
}

 /* Tablet*/
@media  only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px)
{
  .sections {
  -webkit-column-gap:41px;
  -moz-column-gap:41px;
  column-gap:41px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
  
}

 /* Desktop */
@media  only screen and (min-width:769px)
{
  .sections {
  -webkit-column-gap:41px;
  -moz-column-gap:41px;
  column-gap:41px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
  
}

.section {
  -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-before: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.open {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sections">
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x310" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    
    <a href="#" class="open">Open & raise height</a>
    <div class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x320" />
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x330" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x340" />
  </div>
  <div class="section">
  <a href="#" class="open">Open & raise height</a>
    <div class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x320" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="open">Open & raise height</a>
    <div class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x320" />
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its exactly what I use, but the problem another - our columns can dynamically change height (opening forms inside, etc) In this case we see that columns moving and collapsing when height changed

Comment: Whats expected behavior then? won't it overlap if it doen't move ?